# Does _msdcs needs to have Zone Transfer enabled with 2 domain controllers

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, msdcs

I have _msdcs Active Directory Integrated. Do I need to enable Zone transfers and notifications on changes? I have 2 domain controllers with DNS/DHCP enabled on them? I would think yes, but it's disabled and I am not sure why? Windows 2008 R2 controllers were migrated from Windows 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should replicate using AD replication, therefore zone transfer settings should be irrelevant.

Do you have any DNS and/or AD replication issues?

Comment: In my other question you can see problems with BPA. It reports some problems so I'm wondering what's the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are AD integrated, they do not need zone transfers enabled.  Turning that option on would only be needed for standard zone transfers (e.g. you had a bind secondary).